# Reactjs Stripe Test Payment

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Hello I would like to make a Test Payment for my Work-in-Progress Webshop. (Frontend in React, Backend is .Net)

[image: 1]

As you can see in my first image i have started the App and Server on my PC but if I now make a Payment it does not show up in my Test-Dashboard. Why is that?

[image: 2]

I tried to make payment.

Comment: Aren't your second screenshot the payments you performed? If they are not, how were these payments completed?

Comment: no they were performed manually by another c# app. i want to use the intigrated tool from stripe.